# Step by step procedure to host an asp.net website in iis?

Tags: asp.net, iis, hosting

Can someone give me Step by step procedure to host an asp.net website in iis...

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure the framework is installed.
2. Put your site on the system somewhere and create a virtual directory that points towards it, making sure that it is an application.
3. Check the ASP.net tab to make sure that the version you are using is selected.
4. Done (bar whatever application level configuration you need).

Answer (score 1):

These references might help.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178610(VS.85).aspx

http://www.beansoftware.com/asp.net-tutorials/deploy-asp.net.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Deploy_web_application.aspx