# How to configure IIS first time for any web app?

Tags: asp.net

I have a website made in ASP.NET .Currently is being opened directly with Visual Studio.
Now i want this to be opened with localhost with IIS features enabled.

I need steps to make this website totally IIS enabled

Comment: I've added an answer that covers some ways of doing this; at a "broad brush-strokes" level of detail. It'd be **very** useful for others to know both what verion of Visual Studio you're using, what version of asp.net you're working on and what version of IIS you're targeting =)

Comment: check this out as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712814/step-by-step-procedure-to-host-an-asp-net-website-in-iis

Comment: do you mean launch the site in Visual Studio and use IIS for debugging? For example IIS Express?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1- You have to Publish your website with Visual Studio

2- Create a Virtual Directory (or Web Application ) on Your IIS

3- Map Your published website to IIS Alias

4- Change your web.config settings if it is necesary

5- Check if you need to  add some new HttpModule to your application

6- Browse your website with http://Localhost/YourIISApplicationName

Comment: "2- Create a Virtual Directory (or Web Application ) on Your IIS" <-- WTF It's a website, not a sub application of a website.

Comment: @Phill; there's a fair chance the OP means they clicked "New Web Site" in the Visual Studio menu, so @Nasser's suggestion is valid, though could be improved by saying "Create a Virtual Directory/Web Application or a new IIS Website". Website != the only thing hosted at `www.mysite.com`, and hasn't meant specifically that for a long time.

Answer (score 3):

Check these tutorials [How to setup an ASP.NET website with IIS](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Set-Up-IIS-ASP.NET.aspx) & 
[How to host an ASP.NET application in IIS](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1247-how-to-host-aspnet-application-on-the-web-server-iis-.aspx) the latter one uses IIS 7 (I guess)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712814/step-by-step-procedure-to-host-an-asp-net-website-in-iis